# git-status reports everything clean but git-pull complains about unstaged changes

Tags: git, git-pull, git-status

Could somebody explain to me the following output?

```
[user@ hostname /dir]% git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

It took 11.81 seconds to enumerate untracked files. 'status -uno'
may speed it up, but you have to be careful not to forget to add
new files yourself (see 'git help status').
nothing to commit, working directory clean
[user@ hostname /dir]% git pull
Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
[user@ hostname /dir]% git --version
git version 2.4.8
[user@ hostname /dir]%
```

Comment: I'm not sure about how helpful this question is. I'm still unclear what happened here -- also because I deleted the directory in question. I think these problems were caused by a crazy NFS disk. Very often I found a .git/.lock file laying around without any leftover git process. Once git clean -fd failed due to some directories being readonly. So I'm fine with deleting this question. Of course the answer is helpful in point of view of how to debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The message itself comes from [`git-sh-setup.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8545932d45c91437ac439b1a2df12cf397f71311/git-sh-setup.sh#L209), which [git-pull.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8545932d45c91437ac439b1a2df12cf397f71311/git-pull.sh#L242) (in Git version 2.4.8) invokes to make sure that it's OK to do a `git pull` that will run `git rebase`.

What's not clear is why `git diff-files` is exiting with a nonzero status (see the line above the directly linked line in `git-sh-setup.sh`), even though `git status` says that there is nothing to commit.  Running `git diff-files` manually, to get its actual output, might be enlightening.